# Customizing org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User for handling custom properties of User

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security

What would be the way of customizing the `org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User` which handles authentication on the basis of `enabled`, `accountNotExpired`, `credentialsNotExpired` and `accountNotLocked`? My application User(DB) has the following possible status:

`PENDING`, `ACTIVE`, `DEACTIVATED`, `BLOCKED`, `SPAM`, `DELETED`

I have written a custom `UserDetailsService`

```
@Service
public class MyUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {

    @Autowired
    private UserDao userDao;

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        User user = userDao.findByEmail(username)
                .orElseThrow(() -> new UsernameNotFoundException("No account found for " + username));

        return new org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User(user.getEmail(),
                user.getPassword(),true , true, true, true, getAuthorities("ROLE_USER"));
    }
    
     private Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities(String role) {
            return Arrays.asList(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(role));
     }

}
```

As of now, I am forced to hard code the `true` to all the properties the Spring's `User` have by default. I want my own implementation of those properties.

**Edit: Working of my custom Account status:**
For `spam`, `delete` I want user to decide(at login point) if they want to recover their account. For `spam` and `blocked` the user will be able to access the home page but nothing would be visible other than a message. For `deactivated` I want to show the users that they needs to activate the account by clicking on the link specified in the email they received.
How to achieve this? And at what level?

Comment: maybe you sholdby get the User Entity into variable after that validate informations to return User or not, because this method return user if is valid

Comment: Do you really want spam, deleted etc. accounts to pass authentication which is what has happened when you get this far? Don't you want to reject them at the authentication step? If you are offering an account recovery service then it might be best to implement that in a separate service away from your main system.

Comment: @AndyBrown For spam, `delete` I want user to decide(at login point) if they want to recover their account. For `spam`, `blocked`, the user will be able to access the home page but nothing would be visible other than a message. For `deactivated` i want to show the users that they needs to activate the account by clicking on the link specified in the email they received. How to achieve this? And at what level? Would be thankful to you if could post an answer

Comment: OK, would it work for you to forget about extending the user entity and instead add granted authorities that reflect the rights of the user: e.g. ROLE_ACTIVE, ROLE_SPAM, ROLE_DELETED. Authorities can be used to protect web server endpoints and can be examined in code to make more complex logic decisions.

Comment: @AndyBrown It's not a good advice to take advantage of grand authorities on behalf of a user account status because it reduce readability and also if sometime in the future the application grows to need real role feature it would be a complete mess to handle . the best course of action is to add an account status field (while extending from user) and use that info

Answer (score 1):

Simply you can extend `org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User` class add new fields and methods (or override existing if you need), maybe it could be easier way than creating new kind of user object which implements `UserDetails` interface.

Comment: I liked this idea and I've implemented it this way, as it helps to not have to overwrite the whole authenticator and implement all checks again. Why did this not receive more upvotes? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

> **First:** Extend your `User` class from  `UserDetails` and add necessary fields like username , password and etc.
>
> **Second:** add `enabled`, `accountNotExpired`, `credentialsNotExpired` and `accountNotLocked` fields to it and make
>   the last three as `transient` as you don't want to persist them, you
>   just use them to check if these criterias are method or not.

```
public enum UserStatus{
    PENDING,
    ACTIVE,
    DEACTIVATED,
    BLOCKED,
    SPAM,
    DELETED
}


public class User implements UserDetails {

    //  ... Other field definitions 
    protected LocalDateTime expireDate;
    protected UserStatus status = UserStatus.ACTIVE;   // load from DB
    @Transient
    protected boolean accountNotExpired = true;

    @Transient
    protected boolean accountNotLocked = false;

    @Transient
    protected boolean credentialsNotExpired = true;

    // ...  getters & setters
}
```

---

> Implement your `userService` by implementing your custom methods from
>   `UserService` and also more importantly from `UserDetailsService` to
>   implement the logic of criteria for `accountNotExpired`,
>   `credentialsNotExpired` and `accountNotLocked`.
>
> Here I only implement  `accountNotExpired` for instance , you can add 
>   yours for `credentialsNotExpired` and `accountNotLocked`.

```
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService, UserDetailsService {
    private final UserRepository userRepository;

    @Autowired
    public UserServiceImpl(UserRepository userRepository) {
        this.userRepository = userRepository;
    }

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) {

        User user = userDao.findByEmail(username)
            .orElseThrow(() -> new UsernameNotFoundException("No account found for " + username));

        // check whether you account expired or not
        if ((user.getExpireDate() != null) && (LocalDateTime.now().isAfter(user.getExpireDate()))) {
            user.setAccountNotExpired(false);
        }

        //  Also decide for credentialsNotExpired and accountNotLocked here



        for (Role role: user.getRoles()) {
            for (Permission permission: role.getPermissions()) {
                user.getAuthorities().add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(permission.getName()));
            }
        }

        return user;
    }
}
```

---

> Now based on the criteria implemented on the previous step, you are
>   now at the position of controlling you user  by implementing 
>   `AuthenticationProvider` as :

```
public class CustomAuthenticationProvider implements AuthenticationProvider {

    private final UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    public CustomAuthenticationProvider(UserDetailsService userDetailsService) {
        this.userDetailsService = userDetailsService;
    }

    @Override
    public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) {
        String username = authentication.getName();
        BCryptPasswordEncoder bcrypt = new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
        String password = (String) authentication.getCredentials();
        UserDetails userDetails = userDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(username);
        if (userDetails == null) {
            throw new BadCredentialsException("username not found");
        }
        if (!bcrypt.matches(password, userDetails.getPassword())) {
            throw new BadCredentialsException("password incorrect");
        }
        if (!userDetails.isAccountNonExpired()) {
            throw new CredentialsExpiredException("account expired");
        }
        if (!userDetails.isCredentialsNonExpired()) {
            throw new CredentialsExpiredException("password expired");
        }
        if (!userDetails.isAccountNonLocked()) {
            throw new LockedException("account locked");
        }

        // decision point based on user status   
        if (userDetails.getUserStatus() != UserStatus.DEACTIVATED) {
            throw new DisabledException("account deactivated");
        }else if(userDetails.getUserStatus() != UserStatus.PENDING){
                ...
        }else if(userDetails.getUserStatus() != UserStatus.BLOCKED){
                ...
        }else if(userDetails.getUserStatus() != UserStatus.SPAM){
                ...
        }else if(userDetails.getUserStatus() != UserStatus.DELETED){
                ...
        }


        return new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(userDetails, password, userDetails.getAuthorities());
    }

    @Override
    public boolean supports(Class << ? > authentication) {
        return authentication.equals(UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken.class);
    }
}
```